# Typescript: convert "array of generic objects" to "object of generic objects" while maintaining types

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have a library that I am re-writing to TypeScript and I am struggling with implementing proper types for one feature.

There is a function `createManyWrappers` that takes an array of objects as a parameter but returns object of objects.

Library's source code showing how I tried to solve this (but I failed):

```ts
export function createManyWrappers<WrapperConfigParam extends WrapperConfig<Entity>, Entity>(wrapperConfigs: WrapperConfigParam[]) {
    type Names = WrapperConfigParam['name'];

    const wrappers: { 
        [key in `${Names}Wrapper`]?: Wrapper<Entity>
    } = {};

    for (const wrapperConfig of wrapperConfigs) {
        const nameWithSuffix: `${Names}Wrapper` = `${wrapperConfig.name}Wrapper`;

        wrappers[nameWithSuffix] = createWrapper<Entity>(wrapperConfig);
    }

    return wrappers;
}

function createWrapper<Entity>(wrapperConfig: WrapperConfig<Entity>): Wrapper<Entity>  {
    return {} as Wrapper<Entity>
}

export type WrapperConfig<Entity> = {
    name: string
}

type Wrapper<Entity> = {
    name: string,
    data: Entity
    // .. other properties
}
```

Here is an example of using the library in some application but TS types are not working as I expected:

```ts
type Entity1 = { foo: string };
type Entity2 = { bar: number };
type Entity3 = { cor: number };

const wrapperConfigs = [
    { name: 'entity1' } as WrapperConfig<Entity1>,
    { name: 'entity2' } as WrapperConfig<Entity2>,
    { name: 'entity3' } as WrapperConfig<Entity3>
];

const wrappers = createManyWrappers(wrapperConfigs);

// entity1Wrapper, entity2Wrapper etc should be autosuggested but they are not
const { entity1Wrapper, entity2Wrapper, entity3Wrapper } = wrappers;

const data1 = entity1Wrapper.data // Type of "data1" should be "Entity1"
const data2 = entity2Wrapper.data // Type of "data2" should be "Entity1"
```

Do you have ideas what I can change/fix in either library's code, application code or both to make types working as expected?

1. `entity1Wrapper`, `entity2Wrapper` etc should be properties in `wrappers` object
2. type of eg. `entity1Wrapper.data` should be `Entity1`

[TS playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.2#code/PTAEBkEsCMCcENYE9QGcD2BXWBjApqDugCZ4BQZeAHgA7qwAuoAZpgHY4OTpuGx7wGeALLw2SAOoIaNPLFQAeKfBlyAwj2aQA5gAVE8ALahqQtsVShlq2BrZbtCgKJsuDJAD4ANKBdvPABQA7tKytpo6qABcVqHqEXoGhgDaALoAlKAA3mSgeaDusqAAckZ4lgC8sSphdg76CCkA5GxlTakA3BT5hDyoTCE1ctHZoLk9%20ckA1ngokLwABgAkWaWG5QC%201mELqQD8Mdtyzq6Q7h7jeRugVVkbXZcs9KABRGz9oIM2dTqg6MyfOLheyRTI5Cb5N4fVrrCRnAAWAGVMMwtFQYstVmVUFsgQsbqBMV9agkAHQwvC4oawBYPCF5YnDZIUuEMJEotGpAk4fiCPBHWAnfweYJAn7adJdHobbr5fgMbC8RnyLoysisDhcHh8ARCAVCs6BZXiw5ihIG87pU3Ui2ePLguV4BWwXh3UDwSz6vyGi5q6h0RgFJBFAXi20eAkOvIUmL9WDzbRkNWFAhe07nSOPGNoBjxtjaLyPYiCeAxb3uR4gUCk0l-NlyUA0WDoMJccpJihVgCCMgANpAcIJuLwMNh8L1SBQU7500gAIyRp7oWO5hOge5kaflpAAJkX0EQMTYmEM0AbG63s4AzIuiLAjyez7B1w8oQMzSDtJVQMlHllQNmTR4LOc5NOu7qeh%20Di2nO3h-gBZQxEBs47mB1wetU3zmtuO5wT0-6AcB-hXmhEGYSSn62leFydBQb6AtS348rqIhiJIQKoKK1LiqgkqdmARGGnOAo%20IJ7g7gKJgMDgaDwlgvbEKAZ7upgDDoKgmDaNo5RCMQZD0f%20YnziJJgoSZRlXpJ1xVMqqCvn0TDFgw8ALlURnCUCpJOfAoBVgAKsGBD-KAABE3lziFsnyYpykhduEX6Q5oDeXublmZ53m%20WAAVFMFYUljukWoHJmAKUpBBxSBIVkEAA)

Comment: Does [this code](https://tsplay.dev/WkjeDm) meet your needs? Generally speaking you really want your generic types to depend structurally on their type parameters; [an unused type parameter leads to inference failure or instability](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-type-inference-work-on-this-interface-interface-foot--).  Once you enforce some structural dependence you should be able to strongly type things.  Let me know if you want this written up as an answer or if something is missing.

Comment: wow, yes it's working as expected. Pretty complex but I guess the problem is not an easy one ;) Sure, you can add it as an answer. I will try to incorporate this into my library in a user friendly way hopefully

Comment: BTW I haven't forgotten about this question and I do plan to write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preliminary note: generic type parameter names are conventionally given single uppercase character names like `T` and not long names like `TypeParameter`.  This helps distinguish type parameters from specific types, although it does leave something to be desired when it comes to understanding.  I didn't invent this convention, but I'm going to stick with it in what follows.

---

The biggest issue with your general approach is that TypeScript's type system is [structural](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system) and not [nominal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system); types are compared according to their *structure* or *shape*, as opposed to their *name* or *declaration*.  So if you have want to have a [generic type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-types) like `WrapperConfig<E>` depend on its type parameter `E`, then the *shape* of `WrapperConfig<E>` must depend on `E`.  In your version:

```
type WrapperConfig<E> = {
    name: string
}
```

The type `WrapperConfig<E>` is just `{name: string}` no matter what `E` is.  So `WrapperConfig<Entity1>` is exactly the same type as `WrapperConfig<Entity2>`, and you can't expect the compiler to be able to distinguish them.  Just because you use the *name* `Entity1` in `WrapperConfig<Entity1>`, it doesn't mean there's any relationship between them the compiler can use.

See the [TypeScript FAQ entry on unused type parameters](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-type-inference-work-on-this-interface-interface-foot--) for more information.

---

So any reliance of `WrapperConfig<E>` should be structural; the easiest way to do this is to give `WrapperConfig<E>` a property of type `E`:

```
type WrapperConfig<E> = {
    name: string
    dummyData: E 
}
```

Of course you don't really want to put a value of the type into your configuration object... you really want a nominal type, where `WrapperConfig<Entity1>` depends on `Entity1` merely by *mentioning* the type.  To get behavior like this you can use  [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) in order to lie to the compiler about what values you've given it.  Or you can make it optional and hope the compiler considers that structural enough for its type comparison algorithm:

```
type WrapperConfig<E> = {
    name: string
    dummyData?: E 
}
```

Using phantom properties like this is a way of simulating nominal types, also called "branding" or "tagging".  See [microsoft/TypeScript#202](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/202) for a discussion of nominal-ish typing in TypeScript.

---

Anyway, now we have `WrapperConfig<E>`.  Unfortunately that's not enough information for the compiler to know what keys should be on the return type of `createManyWrappers()`.  It's not enough for the compiler to know that it has a `WrapperConfig<Entity1>`, since such an object is only known to have a `string`-valued `name` property.  No, you need to know the [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of the `name` property.  If it's `"entity1"`, you need to know that.

So you need a more specific type than `WrapperConfig<E>`.  Enter `NamedWrapperConfig<N, E>`:

```
interface NamedWrapperConfig<N extends string, E> extends WrapperConfig<E> {
    name: N
}
```

If you have a value like `{name: "entity1"}`, you can give it a type like `NamedWrapperConfig<"entity1", Entity1>` and then the compiler will know both the key name and the intended entity type.  You *could* do this manually:

```
const e1Config: NamedWrapperConfig<"entity1", Entity1> = {name: "entity1"};
```

but that's tedious, writing out `"entity1"` twice like that.  Another approach is to use a helper function so that `N` can be *inferred* from how you call it:

```
function createWrapperConfig<N extends string, E>(name: N, dummyData: E) {
    const w: NamedWrapperConfig<N, E> = { name };
    return w;
}
```

This function also wants some dummy data so the compiler can infer `E` as well as `N` So you could do this with a real value of that type:

```
const e1: Entity1 = { foo: "" }
const e1Config = createWrapperConfig('entity1', e1);
```

or, equivalently, just use a type assertion:

```
const e1Config = createWrppaerConfig('entity1', null! as Entity1);
```

(Note, the ideal behavior would be something like `createWrapperConfig<Entity1>('entity1')`, but that would require *partial type parameter inference* as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242), but such a feature is not part of the language.  So that `dummyData` parameter is another workaround for it.)

So now we can make your `wrapperConfigs` object:

```
const wrapperConfigs = [
    createWrapperConfig('entity1', null! as Entity1),
    createWrapperConfig('entity2', null! as Entity2),
    createWrapperConfig('entity3', null! as Entity3)
];
```

---

Finally let's give typings to `createManyWrappers()`:

```
function createManyWrappers<W extends NamedWrapperConfig<string, any>>(
    wrapperConfigs: readonly W[]
) {

    const wrappers: {
        [T in W as `${T extends NamedWrapperConfig<infer N, any> ? N : never}Wrapper`]?:
        T extends NamedWrapperConfig<any, infer E> ? Wrapper<E> : never;
    } = {};

    for (const wrapperConfig of wrapperConfigs) {
        const nameWithSuffix = `${wrapperConfig.name}Wrapper`;
        wrappers[nameWithSuffix as keyof typeof wrappers] = createWrapper(wrapperConfig) as any;
    }

    return wrappers;
}
```

I haven't changed the runtime implementation, but there are some changes to typings.  First, the function has just one type parameters, `W`.  You had `W` constrained to a function of another type parameter `E`, but `E` was not actually used in your call signature.  The compiler would not know how to infer `E` from that (it doesn't have a good *inference site*) so it wasn't helping.

Next, in the type of `wrappers`, your version would lose all correlation between the `name` fields and the entity types in `W`.  It would look like `{entity1Wrapper: Entity1 | Entity2 | Entity3; entity2Wrapper: Entity1 | Entity2 | Entity3; entity3Wrapper: Entity1 | Entity2 | Entity3}`.  In order to maintain the correlation you need to iterate over each [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) member of `W`.

Let's examine how this works:

```
{
    [T in W as `${T extends NamedWrapperConfig<infer N, any> ? N : never}Wrapper`]?:
    T extends NamedWrapperConfig<any, infer E> ? Wrapper<E> : never;
}
```

The `[T in W as ...]` syntax is [key remapping in mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) and it lets us iterate over each union member `T` in `W`, and turn it into a key name.  We could have just written `T['name']` to find the name property, but I'm using [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) to show how we treat `T` as `NamedWrapperConfig<N, any>` and infer `N`.  And we append `"Wrapper"` to `N` via [template literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types).  For the value, we do the same thing as we did with `N`, but this time we pull out `E`.

I threw some type assertions into the implementation to suppress any warnings.

---

Okay, let's use it:

```
const wrappers = createManyWrappers(wrapperConfigs);
/* const wrappers: {
    entity1Wrapper?: Wrapper<Entity1> | undefined;
    entity2Wrapper?: Wrapper<Entity2> | undefined;
    entity3Wrapper?: Wrapper<Entity3> | undefined;
} */
```

That type looks as specific as you need, right?

```
const { entity1Wrapper, entity2Wrapper, entity3Wrapper } = wrappers;

// might be undefined after all
if (entity1Wrapper && entity2Wrapper && entity3Wrapper) {
    const data1 = entity1Wrapper.data // Entity1
    data1.foo // string
    const data2 = entity2Wrapper.data // Entity2
    data2.bar // number
    const data3 = entity3Wrapper.data // Entity3
    data3.cor // number
}
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.2#code/FDBmFcDsGMBcEsD2kAE0BOBTAhrTBZbSATwHV1sAHSzdAZwB5SVMAPPSAEzpQDlsAtpk7kqNdAGFkoeAHMGdWOniRZAGhRFiAPm0AKYCiMoA7hWq0pkGbLoAuFFmydkAG2IpSAbQC6wAJQoAN4gxmjIiqbm4vbBhmHGXgAqKCqemjwABgAkQSlsHNx8gsKiFpLScgwqoLR8GlraKAD8fCgOkJgAbrQAvmXimT7NdvEJKPnsmFw8-EIi0ZaV8loaNXUAok2tA7QMW+0onT3oANxjKL0oALzBvecXoIjoKHrQEbBRYkvWciiIoC+5SsNjogRC4yM70gkUgJVI8FgAAsAMrgUAyVg3FA5IJmb4VX6yAB0cKE-UW6Ey50hQJiXjJmARyLRGPgWOwPAA1phiACULBiDR+fjynQfNiMDg8Lt0HpReIQXJApzNCQacZeqFjFhYOB0KgFbQ6OctWAoHAkKgpbgmZT9vojYSbA5ZUr5Ft-K77QcITrMHqDXcMp4fdpgGbBTRQwT3Q7sX6jIyHIplKoLpxwAIBMQACK4bAjFAbFAAelLKAYAFoqyg+eAjphhCg6IghC2lOA4PrsK4UJxMDQuNNoJh-qgS89TJh4OhOAKkSpbKZ4K4+0jvpAIyAVHh0KBsKPivM3csGLwWFMZh20+pi00CtMiqeifHE0cSg5eNvzTAEMg0CcGVKTjC9H2vVMlw0LY9GTep+yzHN81gbAHA2cELmhSITC-EoFljM9eGgppbiCD923uC5dX1Q1TRAKMx1leNSIuODINUNQMwLNCLnLFBiWJf5kTqSh0EQcQEEwOgfz4gBBahXHgaBcCtFtEH1I93gHeihTHDZIAQQUAEYExQJ5EBTJQl0uc4GOLAzEWIAAmUyACNsHQDos1cupKLs-TDOIABmUz3k8o5vN8h4sM+TAjLQhzjNM8yHAAIlSy4QBiukflBbEvEwoC7QIok9AAcmmQKjLKjQ4v8DQ+OrWsoHAOhm0zbMPC6XtwDHJFaEwQrpWK4FlnKyrHKcmqIrXABCEMAsm+qywrJq63UtAiH7RAF3gHhe1bIbbRfGxxsS4LpsgcA5oW86gv8YAfGij4cvoSUisIEhZToeUQOWMFzlLAAqcIYU+J1YnfCbjNlIsmMW4ymgAHxQKABxkTpOA1Ixoec2HvQJfZzqc5HUeHDHhGxlg7vxmNyiJwKgtJtHMAprGIxQIHS2AbKyNxozZVq4nBepxnZUubEIYePiBDkJFPh8sn0ZUZtsFAPdNDXYB4EBPR+fFgAyA3Rcmw3jdxoLZQwsJss4AsTNufXKWJO2UJW+yqq4lCjOJcz3fY2RMJe13sBcx3hedkP3YR5yvdD4l3JePiroEHz0CDsH+wLELw7FyOC2ju646C4kwvdlO0+3IA)